# Jms queue redelivery issues with Spring boot, Atomikos and ActiveMQ

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jms, activemq-classic, atomikos

I'm trying to setup a jms queue and have redelivery behaviour in case the transaction fails. What is happenning is that a message is redelivered (and processed) multiple times because after the message processing code, the session is closed twice. The second close attempt throws an error because it is already closed, so transaction is rollbacked and message redelivered.

Here is my configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class MyJtaConfiguration {

private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(MyJtaConfiguration.class);

@Bean(name = "atomikosUserTransaction")
public UserTransaction atomikosUserTransaction() throws Throwable {
    UserTransactionImp userTransactionImp = new UserTransactionImp();
    userTransactionImp.setTransactionTimeout(10000);

    AtomikosJtaPlatform.transaction = userTransactionImp;

    return userTransactionImp;
}

@Bean(name = "atomikosTransactionManager", initMethod = "init", destroyMethod = "close")
public TransactionManager atomikosTransactionManager() throws Throwable {
    UserTransactionManager userTransactionManager = new UserTransactionManager();
    userTransactionManager.setForceShutdown(false);

    AtomikosJtaPlatform.transactionManager = userTransactionManager;

    return userTransactionManager;
}

@Bean(name = "transactionManager")
@DependsOn({ "atomikosUserTransaction", "atomikosTransactionManager" })
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() throws Throwable {
    UserTransaction userTransaction = atomikosUserTransaction();
    TransactionManager atomikosTransactionManager = atomikosTransactionManager();
    return new JtaTransactionManager(userTransaction, atomikosTransactionManager);
}

@Bean
public QueueConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {     
    Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();
    parameters.put("dataDirectory", "activeMqDataDirectory");
    String brokerUrl = Interpolator.getString("vm://MyBroker?broker.persistent=true&broker.dataDirectory=${dataDirectory}&broker.useJmx=true", parameters );


    ActiveMQXAConnectionFactory activeMQXAConnectionFactory = new ActiveMQXAConnectionFactory(brokerUrl);
    activeMQXAConnectionFactory.setTrustedPackages(
            new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("java.lang,javax.security,java.util,org.apache.activemq,org.fusesource.hawtbuf,com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper,com.brabo".split(","))));

    RedeliveryPolicy redeliveryPolicy = activeMQXAConnectionFactory.getRedeliveryPolicy();
    redeliveryPolicy.setInitialRedeliveryDelay(10 * 1000);
    redeliveryPolicy.setMaximumRedeliveryDelay(10 * 1000);
    redeliveryPolicy.setMaximumRedeliveries(2);

    AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean atomikosConnectionFactoryBean = new AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean();
    atomikosConnectionFactoryBean.setUniqueResourceName("xamq");
    atomikosConnectionFactoryBean.setLocalTransactionMode(false);
    atomikosConnectionFactoryBean.setXaConnectionFactory(activeMQXAConnectionFactory);

    try {
        atomikosConnectionFactoryBean.init();
    } catch (JMSException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory();
    cachingConnectionFactory.setTargetConnectionFactory(atomikosConnectionFactoryBean);
    cachingConnectionFactory.setSessionCacheSize(50);
    cachingConnectionFactory.setExceptionListener(new ExceptionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onException(JMSException exception) {
            LOGGER.error(exception);
        }
    });
    return cachingConnectionFactory;
}


@Bean(name = "myTestQueue")
public Queue backgroundTaskQueue() {
    ActiveMQQueue queue = new ActiveMQQueue("myTestQueue");
    return queue;
}


@Bean
public DefaultMessageListenerContainer backgroundTaskQueueListenerContainer(@Autowired ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
        @Autowired @Qualifier("myServiceProcessorBean") MessageListener messageListener, @Autowired PlatformTransactionManager txManager) {
    return createListenerContainer(connectionFactory, messageListener, txManager, QueueManager.BACKGROUND_TASK_QUEUE_JNDI);
}

private DefaultMessageListenerContainer createListenerContainer(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, MessageListener messageListener, PlatformTransactionManager txManager,
        String destinationName) {       
    DefaultMessageListenerContainer listenerContainer = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();
    listenerContainer.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    listenerContainer.setDestinationName(destinationName);
    listenerContainer.setMessageListener(messageListener);
    listenerContainer.setTransactionManager(txManager);
    listenerContainer.setSessionTransacted(true); 

    listenerContainer.setConcurrentConsumers(1);
    listenerContainer.setReceiveTimeout(3000);
    return listenerContainer;
}
```

}

And

```
@Configuration
@DependsOn("transactionManager")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.myapp.common"}, 
    entityManagerFactoryRef = "myEntityManager", transactionManagerRef = "transactionManager")
@ConfigurationProperties("myapp.ds")
@Validated
public class MyDataSourceConfiguration {

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() throws SQLException {
    OracleXADataSource mysqlXaDataSource = new OracleXADataSource();
    mysqlXaDataSource.setURL(url);
    mysqlXaDataSource.setPassword(password);
    mysqlXaDataSource.setUser(username);

    AtomikosDataSourceBean xaDataSource = new AtomikosDataSourceBean();
    xaDataSource.setXaDataSource(mysqlXaDataSource);
    xaDataSource.setUniqueResourceName("xads");
    xaDataSource.setPoolSize(10);
    xaDataSource.setMaxPoolSize(70);

    xaDataSource.init();
    return xaDataSource;
}

@Bean(name = "myEntityManager")
@DependsOn("transactionManager")
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean customerEntityManager() throws Throwable {

    HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();     
    properties.put("javax.persistence.transactionType",     "JTA");
    properties.put("hibernate.archive.autodetection",       "hbm");
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect",                     "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect");
    properties.put("hibernate.transaction.jta.platform",    AtomikosJtaPlatform.class.getName());
    properties.put("hibernate.generate_statistics",         "false");
    properties.put("hibernate.jdbc_fetch_size",             "2");
    properties.put("hibernate.jdbc.batch_size",             "20");
    properties.put("hibernate.show_sql",                    "false");
    properties.put("hibernate.format_sql",                  "false");
    properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto",                "none");
    properties.put("hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings",   "false"); 

    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManager = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    entityManager.setJtaDataSource(dataSource());
    entityManager.setPackagesToScan("com.myapp.common");
    entityManager.setPersistenceUnitName("myPersistenceUnit");
    entityManager.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);
    entityManager.setPersistenceProvider(new HibernatePersistenceProvider());
    return entityManager;
}
```

}

What could be wrong? The error mentioned above is: ExceptionMapperStandardImpl        : HHH000346: Error during managed flush [Session/EntityManager is closed]

Comment: The issue here seams similar to mine: https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1043619&view=next. Also placing some entityManager.clear() calls seams to fix the issue (of calling twice close) and redelivery to work as appropriate.

Comment: Placing an em.close() at the end of my jms processor, thrown an unexpected OptimisticLockException. This made sense, because I was saving an object to the db in a new transaction, but the persistence context associated with the transaction of the jms processor also contained a reference to an old version of the object. Placing the em.clear, clears the persistence context so this old copy is not written to db when the transaction commits. Still, before placing the flush call the OptimisticLockException did not appear in the log, so I thought to be a configuration issue of XA transactions.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to make sure that the datasource + connectionFactory are init-ed before the transaction manager and closed afterwards. That would already be an improvement by itself, regardless of whether it solves the issue or not.